# Modal Dialog partially off the right side of window

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog window that displays when a user clicks on an actionlink. This dialog works fine, however, it is displayed off the right side of the screen. I can resize the screen, make the window smaller, and this dialog then centers properly and displays appropriate fields.[image: Below is the image off the screen.]

[image]

This image of the dialog displayed center, but I had to modify my window.
Now for my code.

First is the js that I'm using.

```
$(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        // hide dropdown if any
        $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');


        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {


            $('#myModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                //Refresh
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                bindForm();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

}

Next is my view. This is a razor view. The important part is the Modal Placeholder I believe.

```
    @using CRADV.ViewModel
@model CRADV.ViewModel.PreTransmissionViewModel

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.PreTransmissionVariances, rowsPerPage: 11);
    var count = Model.PreTransmissionVariances.Count();
}

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modal.js"></script>


<div>
    <span class="text-primary text-left"> @Html.Label("Record Count: ") </span>
    <span class="text-primary text-right"> @Html.Label(count.ToString()) </span>
</div>

    <!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="myModalContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered",
                headerStyle: "thead-default",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("field_name", "Field Name", canSort: true),
                    grid.Column("previous_month", "Previous Month", canSort: true),
                    grid.Column("current_month", "Current Month", canSort: true),
                    grid.Column("variance", "Variance", canSort: true),
                    grid.Column("is_reviewed", "Is Reviewed", canSort: true, format: (item) => Html.CheckBox("is_reviewed", (bool)(item.is_reviewed == 1), new { @class = "disabled" })),
                    grid.Column("comment", "Comments", format: (item) =>
                        new HtmlString(
                            Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddComment", new CommentViewModel { previous_batch_id = item.previous_batch_id, current_batch_id = item.current_batch_id, field_name = item.field_name },
                                htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "",id = "btnCreate", @class = "" }).ToString()
                                        + " | " +
                            Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewComment", new CommentViewModel { previous_batch_id = item.previous_batch_id, current_batch_id = item.current_batch_id, field_name = item.field_name },
                                htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", id = "btnCreate", @class = "" }).ToString()))))



<div class="form-horizontal col-md-10" id="footer_partial">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.review_date, "Review Date",new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.review_date, htmlAttributes: new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.reviewer, "Reviewer", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.reviewer, htmlAttributes: new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.is_reviewed, "Reviewed", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.is_reviewed, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Then here is the partial view I'm rendering in the modal dialog.

```
@model CRADV.ViewModel.CommentViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabl"> Add Comment to Field</h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "ALS", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "modal-form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.field_name, "Field Name",new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.field_name, new { @class = "form-control disabled" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.comment, "Comment",new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.comment, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.comment)
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.previous_batch_id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.current_batch_id)
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
}
```

Finally my css. This is of course the bootstrap.css file. This is the modal classes.

```
    .modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
          transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1050;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /*margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;*/
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the live website? This is hard to replicate.

Comment: I do not, just running locally at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa

HTML

```
<div class="container demo">


<div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Left Sidebar Modal
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
        Right Sidebar Modal
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal left fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Left Sidebar</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- modal-content -->
    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- modal -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- modal-content -->
    </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- modal -->


</div><!-- container -->

<footer class="demo-footer">
<a href="http://www.bootpen.com" target="_blank">Get more code snippets</a>
</footer>
```

css

```
/*******************************
* MODAL AS LEFT/RIGHT SIDEBAR
* Add "left" or "right" in modal parent div, after class="modal".
* Get free snippets on bootpen.com
*******************************/
.modal.left .modal-dialog,
.modal.right .modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.left .modal-content,
.modal.right .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal.left .modal-body,
.modal.right .modal-body {
    padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}

/*Left*/
.modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
    left: -320px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
    left: 0;
}

/*Right*/
.modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
    right: -320px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    right: 0;
}

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
.modal-content {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
}

.modal-header {
    border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #78909C;
}

.demo {
   padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.demo-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #212121;
    text-align: center;
}

.demo-footer > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}
```